# Google Analytics, the best way to implement the code

Tags: android, google-analytics, screen

I'm developing an Android application, i would implement Google Analytics to track my application.

actually i use this code:

```
 @Override
 public void onStart() {
  super.onStart();
  Tracker tracker = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).getTracker("UA-xxxxxxx-1");
  tracker.set(Fields.SCREEN_NAME, "SCREEN NAME");
  tracker.send(MapBuilder.createAppView().set(Fields.customDimension(1), "Premium").build());
 }
```

I would know some information:

1) Is it or not wrong  implements this code ? Do i must add something in OnDestroy(); function ?

2) i have 5 Activity and i want track it all and i want see in my Google Analytics account the differents screens that user seen during the using of my application, the code that i posted is it  correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an xml file under **res/values/** called analytics.xml

And organize this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<resources>

<!--Replace placeholder ID with your tracking ID-->
<string name="ga_trackingId">UA-xxxxxxx-x</string>

<!--Enable automatic activity tracking-->
<bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

<!--Enable automatic exception tracking-->
<bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>

<string name="com.example.project.Class">Main Activity</string>
<string name="com.example.project.Class2">Activity 2</string>

</resources>
```

And in each Activity class, insert this before you close last bracket:

```
//Tracker methods...

    @Override
      public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // The rest of your onStart() code.


        EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStart(this);  // Add this method.
      }

      @Override
      public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // The rest of your onStop() code.
        EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStop(this);  // Add this method.
      }

      //Tracker method end...
```

**Note:** Imports for tacking will be automatically added. But make sure you have already settled with Google Service and libraries into your project before doing this.

Download the [Google Play Services SDK](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html)

Comment: I have 5 Activity and i want track it all and i want see in my Google Analytics account the differents screens that user seen during the using of my application, how i cand do this ?

What part of your code "get" the "screen name" ?

Tnks for help

Comment: yea as i have explained above add all your activities in analytics.xml and for each activity class place the coding. thats it.

Comment: then you also no need to declare your tracking ID in each activity every time.

Comment: Ahhhhhhhh, i'm sorry now i undestand what you mean !!!
Thanks so much, now i try your code !!! :)

Comment: Only 1 question : how i can increase the update time of google analytics ?

Comment: Opps for your last question: Now there is a Real Time reports lastly released in Analytics. I believe that is the fastest way so far :)